# How can I display an image if the meta_key=x AND meta_value=y in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In my WordPress MySQL DB there is a `meta_key` in `wp_postmeta` table with the value `mazda-certified`. Additionally there is a meta_value associated with the `meta_key` that reads: "Yes" or "No".

I need to figure out how to display an image if and only if the `meta_key=mazda-certified` and the `meta_key=yes`.

Any help with this is tremendously appreciated.

I have been researching this for hours and unfortunately only pulling up information regarding UserMeta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't really know how want to display you image, my easiest way to achieve this, is to create a shortcode that you'll be able to place anywhere you want

In your functions.php file :

```
   add_shortcode('certified-image', 'add_certified_image');

   function add_certified_image($atts, $content = ""){
      global $post;

      if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'mazda-certified', true) == 'yes'){
          $content = '<img src="image-yes.jpg"/>';
      }
      else{
          $content = '<img src="image-no.jpg"/>';
      }
      return $content;
   }
```

In your template :

```
   echo do_shortcode('[certified-image]');
```

It's a short example, read more about add_shortcode [on the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) to add attributes to the shortcode.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I realized what the problem and it was the word 'yes'. In the MYSQL Database is was listed as 'Yes' instead.